# Convert a List of Object arrays to a List of model Beans grouped by id

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a model bean like this:

```
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class MyBean {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> customAttributes;

    // equals and hashCode are implemented based on the id
}
```

From a method call I'm getting a List of `Object` arrays like shown below:

```
// pseudo code
List<Object[]> arr = query.getResultList();


arr[0] = 1, arr[1] = "name 1", arr[2] = "custom_attr_1", arr[3] = "custom_attr_1_val_1"
arr[0] = 1, arr[1] = "name 1", arr[2] = "custom_attr_2", arr[3] = "custom_attr_2_val_1"
arr[0] = 1, arr[1] = "name 1", arr[2] = "custom_attr_3", arr[3] = "custom_attr_3_val_1"

arr[0] = 2, arr[1] = "name 2", arr[2] = "custom_attr_1", arr[3] = "custom_attr_1_val_2"
arr[0] = 2, arr[1] = "name 2", arr[2] = "custom_attr_2", arr[3] = "custom_attr_2_val_2"
arr[0] = 2, arr[1] = "name 2", arr[2] = "custom_attr_3", arr[3] = "custom_attr_3_val_2"

arr[0] = 3, arr[1] = "name 3", arr[2] = "custom_attr_1", arr[3] = "custom_attr_1_val_3"
arr[0] = 3, arr[1] = "name 3", arr[2] = "custom_attr_2", arr[3] = "custom_attr_2_val_3"
arr[0] = 3, arr[1] = "name 3", arr[2] = "custom_attr_3", arr[3] = "custom_attr_3_val_3"
```

I want this `List<Object[]>` to be transformed into `List<MyBean>` such that:

```
// pseudo code
List<MyBean> beans = helpNeededToConvert(List<Object[]>);

// 0th location in the list:
id = 1, name = "name 1", customAttributes = ("custom_attr_1", "custom_attr_1_val_1"), ("custom_attr_2", "custom_attr_2_val_1"), ("custom_attr_3", "custom_attr_3_val_1")

// 1st location in the list:
id = 2, name = "name 2", customAttributes = ("custom_attr_1", "custom_attr_1_val_2"), ("custom_attr_2", "custom_attr_2_val_2"), ("custom_attr_3", "custom_attr_3_val_2")

// 2nd location in the list:
id = 3, name = "name 3", customAttributes = ("custom_attr_1", "custom_attr_1_val_3"), ("custom_attr_2", "custom_attr_2_val_3"), ("custom_attr_3", "custom_attr_3_val_3")
```

That is, merge the items in `List<Object[]>` to a `List<MyBean>` grouped by the `id`.

I can achieve this with the `for` loop and some logic. But just want some help to achieve this with `stream`s and related methods. Populating the `Map<String, Object> customAttributes` is something I am not sure how to achieve.

The ordering of the items in the resulting list is immaterial.

If someone wants to try this, then the below program can be used that populates the `List<Object[]>`:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        List<Object[]> resultList = test.buildResultList();

        // convert to List<MyBean>
    }

    private List<Object[]> buildResultList() {
        List<Object[]> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        Object[] arr1 = new Object[4];
        arr1[0] = 1; arr1[1] = "name 1"; arr1[2] = "custom_attr_1"; arr1[3] = "custom_attr_1_val_1";
        resultList.add(arr1);

        Object[] arr2 = new Object[4];
        arr2[0] = 1; arr2[1] = "name 1"; arr2[2] = "custom_attr_2"; arr2[3] = "custom_attr_2_val_1";
        resultList.add(arr2);

        Object[] arr3 = new Object[4];
        arr3[0] = 1; arr3[1] = "name 1"; arr3[2] = "custom_attr_3"; arr3[3] = "custom_attr_3_val_1";
        resultList.add(arr3);

        Object[] arr4 = new Object[4];
        arr4[0] = 2; arr4[1] = "name 2"; arr4[2] = "custom_attr_1"; arr4[3] = "custom_attr_1_val_2";
        resultList.add(arr4);

        Object[] arr5 = new Object[4];
        arr5[0] = 2; arr5[1] = "name 2"; arr5[2] = "custom_attr_2"; arr5[3] = "custom_attr_2_val_2";
        resultList.add(arr5);

        Object[] arr6 = new Object[4];
        arr6[0] = 2; arr6[1] = "name 2"; arr6[2] = "custom_attr_3"; arr6[3] = "custom_attr_3_val_2";
        resultList.add(arr6);

        Object[] arr7 = new Object[4];
        arr7[0] = 3; arr7[1] = "name 3"; arr7[2] = "custom_attr_1"; arr7[3] = "custom_attr_1_val_3";
        resultList.add(arr7);

        Object[] arr8 = new Object[4];
        arr8[0] = 3; arr8[1] = "name 3"; arr8[2] = "custom_attr_2"; arr8[3] = "custom_attr_2_val_3";
        resultList.add(arr8);

        Object[] arr9 = new Object[4];
        arr9[0] = 3; arr9[1] = "name 3"; arr9[2] = "custom_attr_3"; arr9[3] = "custom_attr_3_val_3";
        resultList.add(arr9);

        return resultList;
    }
}

@Getter @ToString @Builder(toBuilder = true)
class MyBean {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> customAttributes;
}
```

That's how I approached this problem. Looking for better ways to achieve this behavior.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        List<Object[]> resultList = test.buildResultList();

        Map<Integer, List<Object[]>> idObjectsLookup = resultList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> (Integer)o[0]));

        List<MyBean> beans = new ArrayList<>();

        idObjectsLookup.forEach((k, v) -> {
            MyBean mb = new MyBean();
            mb.setId(k);
            Map<String, Object> customAttributes = new HashMap<>();
            for (Object[] arr : v) {
                mb.setName((String)arr[1]);
                customAttributes.put((String)arr[2], arr[3]);
                mb.setCustomAttributes(customAttributes);
            }
            beans.add(mb);
        });

        System.out.println(beans);
    }

    private List<Object[]> buildResultList() {
        List<Object[]> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        Object[] arr1 = new Object[4];
        arr1[0] = 1; arr1[1] = "name 1"; arr1[2] = "custom_attr_1"; arr1[3] = "custom_attr_1_val_1";
        resultList.add(arr1);

        Object[] arr2 = new Object[4];
        arr2[0] = 1; arr2[1] = "name 1"; arr2[2] = "custom_attr_2"; arr2[3] = "custom_attr_2_val_1";
        resultList.add(arr2);

        Object[] arr3 = new Object[4];
        arr3[0] = 1; arr3[1] = "name 1"; arr3[2] = "custom_attr_3"; arr3[3] = "custom_attr_3_val_1";
        resultList.add(arr3);

        Object[] arr4 = new Object[4];
        arr4[0] = 2; arr4[1] = "name 2"; arr4[2] = "custom_attr_1"; arr4[3] = "custom_attr_1_val_2";
        resultList.add(arr4);

        Object[] arr5 = new Object[4];
        arr5[0] = 2; arr5[1] = "name 2"; arr5[2] = "custom_attr_2"; arr5[3] = "custom_attr_2_val_2";
        resultList.add(arr5);

        Object[] arr6 = new Object[4];
        arr6[0] = 2; arr6[1] = "name 2"; arr6[2] = "custom_attr_3"; arr6[3] = "custom_attr_3_val_2";
        resultList.add(arr6);

        Object[] arr7 = new Object[4];
        arr7[0] = 3; arr7[1] = "name 3"; arr7[2] = "custom_attr_1"; arr7[3] = "custom_attr_1_val_3";
        resultList.add(arr7);

        Object[] arr8 = new Object[4];
        arr8[0] = 3; arr8[1] = "name 3"; arr8[2] = "custom_attr_2"; arr8[3] = "custom_attr_2_val_3";
        resultList.add(arr8);

        Object[] arr9 = new Object[4];
        arr9[0] = 3; arr9[1] = "name 3"; arr9[2] = "custom_attr_3"; arr9[3] = "custom_attr_3_val_3";
        resultList.add(arr9);

        return resultList;
    }
}

@Getter @ToString @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
class MyBean {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> customAttributes;
}
```

Comment: ```javax.persistence.query.getResultList()``` returns ```List<Object[]>```. Some custom attributes returned from DB can have float values as well.

Comment: I just now posted my imperative code. Looking for suggestions to doing it in a better way.

Comment: Good, does `MyBean` overrides `equals/hashCode` ? If yes, based on which properties these methods implemented?

Comment: Yes, it can implement these methods on id field. Would that help make solution better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that, we need to group the data by `id` and `name`.

For that, we can create an intermediate *map*. The key of this map should contain two peaces of information `id` and `name`. A quick and dirty way is to concatenate these properties as a string, or wrap them with a list or array of `Object` type, which even is a more nasty workaround.

The proper way of doing this with Java 8 would to define a separate class as data carrier for the *keys* and with Java 16 onwards, we can define it as a record. But since you've said that `MyBean` implements `equals/hashCode` contract based on the `id` property, we can use it as *key* in the intermediate map.

For convenience, I've added one method `parse()` to the `MyBean` class (if this change is undesirable, you can extract it away from the class and place this logic into the collector).

```
public class MyBean {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> customAttributes;
    
    public MyBean(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public static MyBean parse(Object[] args) {
        return new MyBean((Integer) args[0], (String) args[1]);
    }
    
    // getters, setters, equals/hashCode, toString
}
```

To generate a map using Stream API we can make use of the *collector* `groupingBy()`. As a `classifier` we need to provide function that creates a key - `MyBean` based on array `Object[]`. And a downstream collector we can use a collector that combines all "custom attributes" mapped to the same *key* into a map.

Then we can create a stream over the entries of the intermediate map and parse each entry into `MyBean`. And finally collect the beans into a list.

That's how it might look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object[]> arrays = buildResultList();

    List<MyBean> beans = arrays.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyBean::parse,
            Collector.of(
                HashMap::new,
                (Map<String, Object> map, Object[] arr) -> map.put((String) arr[2], arr[3]),
                (left, right) -> { left.putAll(right); return left; })
        ))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new MyBean(entry.getKey().getId(),
            entry.getKey().getName(),
            entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    beans.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

And since `MyBean` is mutable, take advantage of this by reusing the *keys*. Note that it's not considered to be a good practice to change the state of the attributes of the lambda expression, for that reason to mutate the key of the map a plain I'm using an enhanced `for` loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object[]> arrays = buildResultList();

    Map<MyBean, Map<String, Object>> attributesByBean = arrays.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyBean::parse,
            Collector.of(
                HashMap::new,
                (Map<String, Object> map, Object[] arr) -> map.put((String) arr[2], arr[3]),
                (left, right) -> { left.putAll(right); return left; })
        ));

    List<MyBean> beans = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (Map.Entry<MyBean, Map<String, Object>> entry : attributesByBean.entrySet()) {
        MyBean k = entry.getKey();
        k.setCustomAttributes(entry.getValue());
        beans.add(k);
    }
    
    beans.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output:*

```
MyBean{id=3, name='name 3', customAttributes={custom_attr_2=custom_attr_2_val_3}}
MyBean{id=1, name='name 1', customAttributes={custom_attr_2=custom_attr_2_val_1}}
MyBean{id=3, name='name 3', customAttributes={custom_attr_3=custom_attr_3_val_3}}
MyBean{id=3, name='name 3', customAttributes={custom_attr_1=custom_attr_1_val_3}}
MyBean{id=2, name='name 2', customAttributes={custom_attr_3=custom_attr_3_val_2}}
MyBean{id=1, name='name 1', customAttributes={custom_attr_3=custom_attr_3_val_1}}
MyBean{id=2, name='name 2', customAttributes={custom_attr_1=custom_attr_1_val_2}}
MyBean{id=1, name='name 1', customAttributes={custom_attr_1=custom_attr_1_val_1}}
MyBean{id=2, name='name 2', customAttributes={custom_attr_2=custom_attr_2_val_2}}
```